# Регулярное выражение для Имени и Фамилии

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Помогите с регулярным выражением. Необходимо чтобы выполнялось условие - должно быть два слова (по логике имя и фамилия), в которых могут быть строчные и заглавные буквы русского и английского языков, также в любом из слов может быть символ "-" и всего один пробел между ними.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/146901/

Comment: Хуа́н Ка́рлос I де Бурбон (исп. Juan Carlos I de Borbón y Borbón-Dos Sicilias). Ну не бывает регулярок для имени/фамилии

Comment: Я как понимаю у вас имя/фамилия в 1 переменную что ли тянутся???
В идеале вам бы отдельно каждое вводить и тогда уже глядеть

Answer (score 1):

Берем буквы латинского алфавита, всю кириллицу из UTF-8 и символ -. Разделяем одним пробелом, затем берем такую же конструкцию. Не забываем начало строки и конец строки для точного соответствия и не вымирания из контекста

```js
const regex = /^([\w\u0401\u0451\u0410-\u044f\-]+)\s([\w\u0401\u0451\u0410-\u044f\-]+)$/gm;
const str = `Иван-васильевич Василевский-Смехоплясов
Иванов Иван
John Connor
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: 1. Бррррррррррр. 2 Ёё?

Comment: `------ -----` - Отличное имя. А вот Остап Ибрагим Берта-Мария Бендер-бей - не пройдет. Нам аферисты не нужны.